# How to call JS-Functions only on HTML pages where they are being used and not on all of them?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a demo-website for a fictional company.

The most of it is written in Javascript but I have a problem that all my functions are getting called on every HTML-page, even if they are not getting used.

Example: I have a Contact page where only one function should be called, but right now all functions are being called. Those for my Booking page and so on.

I am trying to use window.addEventListener together with window.location.pathname without result.

```
function start() {
// variable for pathname. split in to substrings by '/'
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

// check the last substring of the array for determening which script to 
run
if(pathArray[pathArray.length-1] == "contact.html")
  {
    browserDetect();
  }
  else if(pathArray[pathArray.length-1] == "ourfleet.html")
  {
    showFirstFleetImg();
    showFleetImg();
  }
  else if(pathArray[pathArray.length-1] == "employees.html")
  {
    showFirstStaffImg();
    showStaffImg();
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

One of the functions

```
function showFleetImg(arrayno) {
var fleethtml = "";
var caption = document.getElementById("planename");

for(var i = 0; i < fleetarray.length; i++) {
    fleethtml = fleethtml + "<a href = '#' onclick = 'showFleetImg(" + i + 
"); return false; '><img src='" + fleetarray[i] + "' /></a>";
  }

fleetimage.src = fleetarray[arrayno];
caption.innerHTML = planename[arrayno];
document.getElementById("fleetthumbs").innerHTML= fleethtml;
  }

function showFirstFleetImg(imgnum) {
 showFleetImg(0);
}

window.addEventListener("load", showFirstFleetImg, false);
```

What more do I add, or how do I structure this right so function X is only called in HTML file Y?

Comment: You need to render the file at a page level instead of loading it for the entire website. Right now you are probably loading every file at the header. You need to create Layouts that load only the JS files required.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating individual files for one-off solutions :) having a base JS file is great; but for commonly used scripts.  Specific scripts can exist independently and reserved to load only on the page(s) they're needed on

Comment: @RickS yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish but without luck. Have read through all pages in the course litterature but cant find how to do this part.

Comment: @Doug so my only shot would be to create one JS-file for every solution (html-page)?

Comment: @GuruGuruGuru are you just writing pure HTML and JS? or are you working with any other technologies?

Comment: @RickS pure JS and HTML

Comment: (continuing from your reply to my comment above...) no, you have a lot of different things you could potentially do! Other than individual files you can detect specific elements on unique pages and trigger loading scripts off of that. You can write JS directly on your HTML pages where they are used.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for something like ES Modules. There is a lot of information here http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html, but the gist is they encapsulation javascript code so that functions aren't executed right away.

If you rewrite your javascript file to something like

// foo.js

```js
export function showFleetImg(arrayno) {
var fleethtml = "";
var caption = document.getElementById("planename");

for(var i = 0; i < fleetarray.length; i++) {
    fleethtml = fleethtml + "<a href = '#' onclick = 'showFleetImg(" + i + 
"); return false; '><img src='" + fleetarray[i] + "' /></a>";
  }

fleetimage.src = fleetarray[arrayno];
caption.innerHTML = planename[arrayno];
document.getElementById("fleetthumbs").innerHTML= fleethtml;
  }

export function showFirstFleetImg(imgnum) {
 showFleetImg(0);
}
```

and then your other js file will look like

```
import {showFleetImg, showFirstFleetImg} from './foo.js'
function start() {
// variable for pathname. split in to substrings by '/'
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

// check the last substring of the array for determening which script to 
run
if(pathArray[pathArray.length-1] == "contact.html")
  {
    browserDetect();
  }
  else if(pathArray[pathArray.length-1] == "ourfleet.html")
  {
    showFirstFleetImg();
    showFleetImg();
  }
  else if(pathArray[pathArray.length-1] == "employees.html")
  {
    showFirstStaffImg();
    showStaffImg();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the code you've posted to suggest each function should first every time.

However, there are many better ways to do what you're trying to do.

- Use separate JS files and call into each page only those that need to be executed
- If you prefer to use one JS file like currently, don't conditionalise based on pathname; what if your filename changes? You'd have to update your JS each time.

As regards the latter point, it would make more sense to act on the presence (or lack thereof) of a data attribute on the body identifying which page is currently showing.

HTML

```
<body data-page='contact'>
```

JS

```
switch (document.body.getAttribute('data-page')) {
    case 'contact': /* do something */ break;
    case 'fleet': /* do something else */ break;
    //etc...
}
```

Note also the use of `switch()` rather than duplicative `if`/`else if` statements.

[Edit - or have a look at Modules as per @user1816294's answer]